# ¿Por qué mis peticiones a veces funcionan y a veces no?

Tags: python, rest, sql-server-2014

Estoy programando una Api Rest con Angular, Python y SqlServer. En una parte llamo 3 funciones para traer datos de 3 tablas diferentes.
Y cuando entro a la pagina que las ejecuta, se manda la petición GET, la recibe la api en python pero esta AVECES se traba.
Lo que me causa confunsion es que no siempre es el mismo resultado, a veces funciona todo bien, a veces solo trae datos de una tabla otras veces de 2 tablas nomas.
El error que aparece en el Exception es "No results.  Previous SQL was not a query."

```
@app.route('/catPriority', methods=['GET'])#OBTENER LAS PRIORIDADES
def catPrio():
    try:
        print("ENTER TRY OF PRIORITIES")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CatPrioridad;")
        print("RUN QUERY FOR PRIORITY")
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]#Crea una array con la misma cantidad que el cursor
        ['name', 'create_date']
        results = []#Crea array donde se almacenara
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            # append agrega el dato al final de la lista
            results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))#Guarda las columnas con su valor
        conn.commit()
        return {'intResponse': 200, 'strAnswer': 'CAT PRIORIDADES OK', 'Result':results} 
    except:
        print("EXCEPT IN PRIORITY")
        return {'intResponse': 500, 'strAnswer': 'CAT PRIORIDADES FAIL', 'Result':None}

########################################   MEDIO   ####################################################

@app.route('/catMedio', methods=['GET'])#OBTENER LOS MEDIOS
def catMedio():
    try:
        print("ENTER TRY OF MEDIA")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CatMedio;")
        print("RUN QUERY FOR MEDIA")
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]#Crea una array con la misma cantidad que el cursor
        ['name', 'create_date']
        results = []#Crea array donde se almacenara
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            # dict = https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-dict-python/
            # zip = https://micro.recursospython.com/recursos/la-funcion-zip.html
            # append agrega el dato al final de la lista
            results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))#Guarda las columnas con su valor
        conn.commit()
        return {'intResponse': 200, 'strAnswer': 'CAT MEDIOS OK', 'Result':results} 
    except:
        print("EXCEPT IN MEDIA")
        return {'intResponse': 500, 'strAnswer': 'CAT MEDIOS FAIL', 'Result':None}

 ########################################   CATEGORIA   ####################################################

@app.route('/catCateg', methods=['GET'])#OBTENER LOS MEDIOS
def catCateg():
    try:
        print("ENTER TRY OF CATEGORIE")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CatCategoria;")
        print("RUN QUERY FOR CATEGORIES")
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]#Crea una array con la misma cantidad que el cursor
        ['name', 'create_date']
        results = []#Crea array donde se almacenara
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            # dict = https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-dict-python/
            # zip = https://micro.recursospython.com/recursos/la-funcion-zip.html
            # append agrega el dato al final de la lista
            results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))#Guarda las columnas con su valor
        conn.commit()
        return {'intResponse': 200, 'strAnswer': 'CAT CATEGORIAS OK', 'Result':results} 
    except:
        print("EXCEPT IN CATEGORIES")
        return {'intResponse': 500, 'strAnswer': 'CAT CATEGORIAS FAIL', 'Result':None}
```

Comment: Prueba generando un mensaje más diciente del error que posiblemente estés atrapando. Usa `except Exception as er: print(er)` en vez de pintar simplemente tu texto en los bloques Except. Prueba y vuelve con lo que salga ahí cuando falle alguna de tus consultas; edita tu pregunta y añade lo que salga en el mensaje de error

Comment: El error que aparece es el de "No results.  Previous SQL was not a query."